retries feature for subtask did not work as excepted when we have global retries in airflow
I have dag on airflow contain some sub tasks I need to declare for each task specific retry_delay i try to use     retries= 3, and retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=30), in the subtask but the retry for this subtask run after 1 second (as decalre it on global inside the dag) not after 30 minutes
below is the part of airflow dags :
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils import timezone
import os
from os import popen
import subprocess
from globalFunction import Checker
from globalFunction import convertNumberToDate
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
import sys
import psycopg2
from airflow.models import Variable

args = {
    'owner': 'daasuser',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(150),
    'email': ['test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': ['test.com'],
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'catchup':False,
}

formatted_date_minus_1_yyyymmdd = date_minus_1.strftime("%Y%m%d")
yyyymmdd_formatted_timestamp = current_timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d")

def compare_values(api_name,extraction_time,data_partition):
    x = get_number_of_lines_from_audit_postgres(f'{api_name}', f'{extraction_time}')
    z = get_number_of_lines_from_final_table_presto(f'{api_name}', f'{data_partition}')
    if x == z and x > 0 and z > 0:
        print(f"Values are equal: {x}")
    else:
        print(f"Values are not equal: Postgres_audit_table={x}, Presto_audit_table={z}")
        sys.exit(1)


VALIDATE_USER_API_INGESTION = PythonOperator(
    task_id='VALIDATE_USER_API_INGESTION',
    python_callable=compare_values,
    op_kwargs={'api_name': 'API_USER', 'extraction_time': f'{yyyymmdd_formatted_timestamp}', 'data_partition': f'{formatted_date_minus_1_yyyymmdd}'},
    retries= 3,
    retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=30),
    dag=dag,
)


VALIDATE_USER_API_INGESTION 

the excepted is to run the retry of VALIDATE_USER_API_INGESTION subtask after 30 minutes not after 1 second

can you add the entire code, or the part where you define the Dag? I believe this part is missing in the example
